# How can I have a custom class inherit from multiple superclasses?

Tags: ios, inheritance, uiviewcontroller

I have a an iPhone app in which class **A** is a subclass of **UIViewController**:

[image]

Now I'm creating a new app, in which I want to re-use **A**, but have it subclass from **B**, which is fine, because **B** subclasses from **UIViewController**:

[image]

But now I have another class, **C**, which is a subclass of **GLKViewController**:

[image]

The problem comes when I try to make a third app which re-uses **B** without any changes.  Since **B** inherits from **UIViewController**, I need to somehow tell **C** that it should inherit from **B** *and from* **GLKViewController**, which I believe is a case of multiple inheritance:

[image]

From what I'm reading, the best way to handle this is with *composition*, but I don't understand how to best apply it to my situation.

As a stand-in solution, I realized I could just create a *wrapper* class **D** which I can then modify on an app-by-app basis to subclass from the appropriate superclass for the task at hand:

[image]

[image]

But that seems kind of hacky.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What's a UIScrollViewController?

Comment: How about using a category on UIViewController instead of subclassing it? As UIScrollViewController inherits from UIViewController, your category would be usable in cases of instances of UIScrollViewController as well. Ow, and really well drafted question +1 for that!

Comment: you can't do that in Objective-C is single inheritance -- like java

use a paradigm of composition or delegation

Comment: @Daij-Djan I mean to say that the way you wrote it, it is not correct. You are correct with the results for the specific case of the question asked. You are incorrect with the broad statement of iOS not supporting the concept of multiple inheritance - if you sticked to Objective-C as you are now, then you are correct. Please do not feel assaulted - that is not my intension.

Comment: @jrturton thanks for the correction- changed it to GLKViewController as a better example.

Comment: @till that sounds interesting, what would that look like in code?

Comment: @Till Your argument *very much* sounds like nitpicking. The fact that all modern programming languages are turing complete means that you can express every language in terms of every other language. That leads to the conclusion that multiple inheritance is supported everywhere. It's just not helpful, like in this specific case (subclassing Cocoa-Touch classes) where I feel it's sensible to state: multiple inheritance is not supported.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe point taken. I feel sometimes nitpicking is needed for making sure people do not mix apples with oranges.

Comment: @Till to THAT I agree :) and I get your point. I was 'sloppy'

Comment: @Daij-Djan I really am glad that we sorted that out... cheers! :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Objective C only supports single inheritance. In this case you'd probably want to use protocols for common functionality. You can use a helper object to implement the protocol methods. In this case, you're not interested in whether your object is a member of a particular class, but whether it implements a specific set of methods.

Comment: I'm curious which class you're referring to when you say "you're not interested in whether your object is a member of a particular class" -- the UIViewController or B?  Because I'm pretty sure I actually am interested in it being part of both classes, both in terms of having access to instance variables and methods.

Comment: Correct, protocols allow similar features to multiple inheritance. Unfortunately, they do not allow default implementations which often leads to code duplication pr a little less elegant solutions that rely on class clusters (helper objects, as you call them). Anyways, from the outside perspective that could be a great replacement.

Answer (score 3):

you can't do that in Objective-C is single inheritance -- like java or most of the other modern languages.

use a paradigm of composition or delegation

Comment: fixed -- removed ios from the comment

Comment: ...and I removed the possibly harsh sounding comment... :D

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly get that covered by using a category. It certainly is not the same as multiple inheritance but sometimes does the job.

Let me draft an example for a category and see if that does what you aim for.

Header: `UIViewController+MyAwesomeExtension.h`

```
@interface UIViewController (MyAwesomeExtension)
- (void)doSomething;
@end
```

Implementation: `UIViewController+MyAwesomeExtension.m`

```
@implementation UIViewController (MyAwesomeExtension)
- (void)doSomething
{
    NSLog(@"doing something totally awesome");
}
@end
```

Now you are using it from within one of your `UIViewController` subclasses which also includes  like e.g. `GLKViewController` ...

Implementation:

```
#import "UIViewController+MyAwesomeExtension.h"
...
[self.viewControllerDerivedClass doSomething];
...
```

Note that such category does have its limits. To find out more, how about researching the subject a bit further.

---

Overall, I think the "most" correct answer would be using protocols to get as close to multiple inheritance as possible, as Mike C. drafted in his answer. My answer is mostly a workaround for simple cases.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure that a category would do the trick here- my class A relies on inheriting both instance variables and instance methods both from B and from UIViewController (or GLKViewController) and A also becomes the File's Owner for a .xib file.  So it's not clear if a category could do all of those things.